# Can I execute a string command in Node?

Tags: node.js

If I construct a function or list of commands that are stored in a string variable, is there a way I can execute them in node and retain what is returned in another variable?  i.e.

```
var result = executeMyCoolStringCommands(myStringVariableWithCommands);
```

Comment: What is "executeMyCoolStringCommands" function and "myStringVariableWithCommands" variable?  Show us some code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, we all know evils of using `eval`, however the [npm module eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval) avoids its use yet executes a string

```
var _eval = require('eval')
var res = _eval('var x = 123; exports.x = x')

console.log("here is res ", res);
```

which outputs :

```
here is res  { x: 123 }
```

Answer (score 13):

option `-e` will let you run arbitary text as node.js source code:

`node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify({}))"`

Answer (score 6):

Node has well-suited VM module, which allows you to run code in a dedicated context.
See https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

E.g.

```
const vm = require('vm');

const x = 1;

const context = { x: 2 };
vm.createContext(context); // Contextify the object.

const code = 'x += 40; var y = 17;';
// `x` and `y` are global variables in the context.
// Initially, x has the value 2 because that is the value of context.x.
vm.runInContext(code, context);

console.log(context.x); // 42
console.log(context.y); // 17

console.log(x); // 1; y is not defined.
```